# What are my options when I can't vote to undelete a question?

Tags: discussion

Yesterday I answered the following question: [Google webfont loader how to unload fonts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28754096/google-webfont-loader-how-to-unload-fonts/28755399#28755399)

Some time after receiving an answer the asker removed the question. While the question seems broad at first, I believe it's a question that may have a more widely applicable audience.

I don't have enough reputation to vote to undelete the question, what other options do I have?
Since it's not against the rules, I've currently replicated the question and the answer [over here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28766532/google-webfonts-how-to-unload-fonts-after-loading-them/) to preserve the information.

Comment: That was a pretty decent question. I would vote to undelete it myself, except now that you have duplicated it I won't. The OP must have had a reason for removing it, and doesn't appear to have a _history_ of asking then deleting, which would raise suspicion, so I suppose in this instance I'd just leave things as they are.

Comment: The OP deleted it.  That's a pretty bone-headed thing to do when you get a good answer, a moderator will probably undelete it.  If that doesn't pan out then just write your own Q+A pair.  Oh, wait, you did.

Comment: @HansPassant its [over there](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28766532/google-webfonts-how-to-unload-fonts-after-loading-them/) already.

Comment: And by the way, enjoy your meta-effect rep from both question _and_ answer now that you've brought it here :)

Answer (score 2):

In general, if you disagree with something that's happened but don't have sufficient reputation to act directly, you should flag **other (needs ♦ moderator attention)**, including as much detail as you can give about why you're doing so.

In this specific case, although it's not clear why the OP removed a question that had upvotes and an answer, I think that given the replication you've carried out (good work, by the way!) it should be left as-is.